# My global variables don't get the NEW values that assigning to it when they are given to the <input> element

Tags: javascript

in my js file the global variables don't get the NEW values that assigning to it when the new values are  given to the .value attribute which located in the  element and still giving me the default values. 
but when i declare variable inside listener function which has the same way to get the value of value attribute, the new value is assigned to it
can you please demonstrate the reason of this behavior?
and thanks in advance

```
<input type="text" id="v" value="9">

<button onclick="my()">read</button>

<script>
  var ff0 = document.querySelector('#v').value

  function my(){
  var ff2 = document.querySelector('#v').value
  alert(

    'ff0 >> ' + ff0 + '\n' +

    'ff2 >> ' + ff2 + '\n'
    )
}
</script>
```

if i give (5) to the input element and click the button, the alert message will be

```
ffo >> 9
ff2 >> 5
```

why don't both of the ff0 and ff2 get the same new value of 5??

Comment: Because `var ff0 = document.querySelector('#v').value` is executed only once - when the page loads the `<script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input type="text" id="v" value="9">

<button onclick="my()">read</button>

<script>
  var ff0 = document.querySelector('#v').value

  function my(){
  var ff2 = document.querySelector('#v').value
  alert(

    'ff0 >> ' + ff0 + '\n' +

    'ff2 >> ' + ff2 + '\n'
    )
}
</script>
```

ff0 has been declared globally so it is filled once and then it is printed and that's it.

ff2 instead behaves in a totally different way, in fact it is declared locally inside a function, the same is triggered when the button is clicked. Then the variable is always refreshed with the entered data.

Comment: *"ff0 has been declared globally so it is filled once"* - I think it's worth mentioning that the reason `ff0` is only set once is simply because there is no line of code that attempts to change it after its initial declaration. The fact that it's declared globally, while correct, doesn't really seem related to the value being unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort my friend @koλzar

Comment: The idea is clear now, thanks for clarification @TylerRoper

Comment: Note that in some circumstances, JavaScript _does_ behave like you expected. If you had written `var ff0 = document.querySelector('#v');` at first, its `.value` would have been 9 at the beginning, but changed to 5 in the my() function.